# Consuming and Filtering Tweets using Twitter4j-4.0.2

Tags: android, twitter, webview, twitter4j

I am trying to get **Tweets** based on **user input string** and **parse tweet text, extract web link from the tweet (ignore tweets without a web link) and parse it to show in WebView Dialog with a next button(so when clicked to move to the next WebView(show next content of the link parsed from tweet))**. I am getting the tweets result (without filtering), how can i filter them and get the URL so i can parse it for the WebView ?

Here is the code i am running on background thread:

```
 @Override
            protected WebView doInBackground(String... strings) {
                //Get userInput
                String searchTerm = strings[0];
                //Initialize Twitter Connection
                ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setDebugEnabled(true);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefConsumerKey(), ""));
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefConsumerSecret(), ""));
                AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefAccessToken(), ""), sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefAccessTokenSecret(), ""));
                Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
                try {
                    //Query object
                    Query query = new Query(searchTerm);
                    //The number of tweets to return per page [max:100]
                    query.count(2);
                    //Return only the most recent results in the response
                    query.resultType(Query.ResultType.recent);
                    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                    Log.e("Twitter QueryResult", result.toString());
                }catch(TwitterException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using twitter4j Library, there is `URLEntity` class which you can get from `twitter4j.Status` by calling `status.getURLEntities();`This will return an Array of `URLEntity`. So here you go, you can check if the tweet has urlEntity inside and you can get the url mentioned in the tweet by calling `urlEntity.getURL();`

**EDIT**
For the answer including code, take a look @hrskrs 's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is the answer in case someone has the same problem:

```
 @Override
        protected WebView doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //Get userInput
            String searchTerm = strings[0];
            //Initialize Twitter Connection
            ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                builder.setDebugEnabled(true);
                builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefConsumerKey(), ""));
                builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefConsumerSecret(), ""));
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefAccessToken(), ""), sharedPreferences.getString(TwitterConstants.getPrefAccessTokenSecret(), ""));
           //Gets Twitter instance with default credentials
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);
            try {
                //Query object
                Query query = new Query(searchTerm);
                //The number of tweets to return per page [max:100]
                query.count(2);
                //Return only the most recent results in the response
                query.resultType(Query.ResultType.recent);
                //Get all results
                QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
                //Fetch only tweets from the results
                List<twitter4j.Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

                for(twitter4j.Status tweet : tweets){
                    //Get single tweet
                    String singleTweet = tweet.getText();
                    Log.e("Twitter Tweet", singleTweet);
                    //Get URLs (it returns an array of Urls)
                    URLEntity[] urlEntity = tweet.getURLEntities();
                    //If the UrlEntity array is not empty
                    if(urlEntity != null){
                        for(int i=0; i<urlEntity.length; i++){
                            //Get URL from the tweet
                            String tweetUrl = urlEntity[i].getURL();
                            Log.e("Tweet URL", tweetUrl);
                        }
                    }else{
                        return null;
                    }
                }

            }catch(TwitterException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(WebView webView) {
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the same answer with what I've answered. It's just the code you added. You need to accept it as right answer.